# Link two Spinner with a button

Tags: button, spinner

I want the user to do this: when they select an item from the first spinner and the item on the other spinner and click on the button they get the result in a `TextView`. How can I do that?

I created already two spinner , `TextView` and one button. For example: if the user select from the first spinner their name and the second spinner their id, when they click to the button the text view will show their telephone number .

UPDATE:

Here is the code for the MainActivity

```
package second.program.p1;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Spinner v1;
Spinner v2;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
TextView T1;
Button b;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    v1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.v1);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.city_names,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    v1.setAdapter(adapter);
    v1.getSelectedItemPosition();



    v2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.v2);
    adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.city_names,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    v2.setAdapter(adapter);



    T1 = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.T1));

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);





}
    };
```

Strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">P1</string>
<string-array name="city_names">
    <item>" "</item>
    <item>"Med"</item>
    <item>"Ryu"</item>
    <item>"Jedd"</item>
    <item>"Hai"</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

So , i want after the user select "Med" from the first spinner (v1) and "Hai" from the second spinner (v2) he press the Button ,after that in the `TextView` will appers the km (the distance between the two cites, but i dont add it yet)

i did the two spinners ,
now what i should do with the `TextView` and the `Button` ?

Comment: This question seems to be of Android, why you need to link those two spinners ? you can get individuals from these two spinners and on button click you can query your db or whatever repository you are using for storing data, to get the number of person with selected Name and ID

Comment: i want the result shown as the user seletion , becuse of this i will add two spinner . so the user can choose one from each spinner and get the result from button

Comment: Yes i understood your problem, partially if not completely, you can take the selection from spinner/s and then query for customer's number, there is no need for these spinners to be interlinked, it is simple like you see on any football site you pick league and date then you click go it shows all matches of teams on that date, it takes those two spinners' input and query db for the output. I hope it is now clear to you, if you are asking how to start doing this thing then there are bunch of tutorials out there

Comment: Thank you Muhammad , this is what i'm looking for , can you please give me the key to search for the tutorials.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spinner_control.htm here you go simple and easy...
https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/material-design/android-spinner-tutorial/

Comment: i looked at them , it looks like the same what i did ,
please look at the question again , i updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have updated the question, so i can now answer it properly,

There are two methods that are provided by Android which we need to override to handle the items selection of spinners.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String cityName = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity, "Selected city: " + cityName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> view) {
    // This method helps when we have to handle when user hasn't selected anything
       from spinner on which further events are dependent.

}
```

Now do button click on your Button **`b`** like this in your onCreate:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){

        String firstCityName = v1.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String secondCityName = v2.getSelectedItem().toString();

        //now you have both items/cities you selected from spinners
        // so its time to do some checks and show user the distance

        if(firstCityName.equals("Meh") && secondCityName.equals("Med"){
            T1.setText("the value which you have stored somewhere");

        } else if(firstCityName.equals("Med") && secondCityName.equals("Ryu"){
              T1.setText("30KM / hardcode it or get the value you stored somewhere");
       } //.... if-else-if for remaining cases
    }

}
```

**Some advices :**

**1-** Please use proper naming conventions.

```
Spinner spinnerStartingCity = new .....
Button btnSubmit = new ....
```

**2-** Topics like these are not so hard to find over internet, first search properly, because what almost all coders DO ?? GOOGLE -> copy/paste !! :D

**3-** Before googling, if you want to be a Developer not just coder, first go through proper tutorials, android dev site, and online tutorials for thorough understanding because learning lasts longer than copy pasting :)

**Happy Developing**

Comment: Thank you very much !! now its clear , i'm a beginner so maybe this is too easy :) i will take your advice , but believe me i did ton of googling for an answer before i write here . 

wish u all the best 
you save me !

Comment: glad to help :) you can accept answer :) good luck to you as well :) no problem, you are beginner,  that's why i wrote advice/s :D